# PolySearcher in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I came across this while browsing through lucy

http://lucy.apache.org/docs/perl/Lucy/Search/PolySearcher.html

Does solr have an equivalent of this? My usecase is exactly the same (reading through multiple indices in a single shard and perform a distribution across shards).

If not can someone give me a hint? I tried swapping readers for a single searcher, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Does Solrs [DistributedSearch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) helps you?

Till 3.x you have to implement your own distribution of documents during indexing e.g. using round robin. But searching across several shards is no problem at all.

Comment: Ya it does. But the problem is not only making a distributed search across shards, it is reading through multiple indices in a single shard and then distributing across shards.

Comment: In short it is a distribution of distributions!

Comment: @greenhorn Actually I still do not really understand what is ment by that. Do you mean multiple shards/cores per machine to allow using of multiple cpu cores in parallel or do you mean something similar to a join?